# Java-Selection sorting an array of objects by an int key and displaying in table

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am currently working on a project for school and am really struggling. I am supposed to selection sort a group of Student objects and then display them in selection sort order.

> Create an array with the size of 10 and assign student details (**Name**, **BroncoId**, **age** and **TotalMarks**) to the array. Perform the selection sort to sort the students in descending order based on their total marks.
>
> a. Steps:
>
> i. Create the student list (use Random class in java to generate the age (15-25) and total (0-100))
>
> ii. Print the Student List in a table format
>
> iii. Perform selection sort based on the total marks of the students

The place I am stuck at currently is making the selection sort. I understand how to create the selection sort, but I can't seem to translate it for this implementation.

My selection sort code:

```
public static Student[] selectionSort(Student[] studentList)
{

    for(int i = 0; i <studentList.length-1; i++)
    {
        int minIndex = studentList[i].getGrades();
        int pos = i;

        for(int j = i + 1; j < studentList.length-2; j++)
        {

            if(studentList[j].getGrades() > studentList[minIndex].getGrades())
            {

                minIndex = studentList[j].getGrades();
                pos = j;

            }

        }

        int temp = studentList[pos].getGrades();
        studentList[pos] = studentList[i];
        int k = studentList[i].getGrades();
        k = temp;

    }
    return studentList;
}
```

When I run this code, the console returns:

I sought tutoring to hopefully fix this problem, but my tutor gave me a few nonfunctional suggestions. We were both stumped at the end of the session.

My code for printing:

```
public static void printStudentInfo(Student[] students)
{


    System.out.println("Name:                                              AGE:  idNumber:  Score:");

    for(Student student: students)
    {
        if(student.getName().length() <= 49)
            System.out.printf("%-50s %-5d %-10s %-4d\n", student.getName(), student.getAge(), student.getID(), student.getGrades() );

        else
        {

            System.out.printf("%-50s %-5d %-10s %-4d\n", student.getName().substring(0,48), student.getAge(), student.getID(), student.getGrades() );

            System.out.println();
            int i = 0;

            while(i <= student.getName().length())
            {

                System.out.printf("%-50s", student.getName().substring(49 +48*i, 97+48*i) );
                System.out.println();
                i++;

            }



        }

    }

}
```

As more of an issue out of passion, I sought to make an interesting print method. My problem is, also that I don't really know how to parse and format a string of 155 characters for instance. What do I put in this while lop to accomplish this?

I want the program to output one object name line like:

> **49 characters**
>   **49 chars**
>   **…**
>   **What ever is left**

It probably won't ever go past three lines, but hey, who says I can't give an example like that? What do I put in the header of the while loop to accomplish this?

PS:
Here is the Student class if you need it.

```
public class Student
{

private String name;
private int age;
private String idNumber;
private int gradePoints;

public Student(String name, int age, String idNumber, int gradePoints)
{

    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.idNumber = idNumber;
    this.gradePoints = gradePoints;

}

public void setName(String name)
{

    this.name = name;

}
public void setAge(int age)
{

    this.age = age;

}
public void setidNumber(String idNumber)
{

    this.idNumber = idNumber;

}
public void setPoints(int gradePoints)
{

    this.gradePoints = gradePoints;

}

public String getName()
{

    return name;

}

public int getAge()
{

    return age;

}

public String getID()
{

    return idNumber;

}

public int getGrades()
{

    return gradePoints;

}
```

Comment: *Create the student list* Yes, use a `List` not an Array, your life will be simpler

Comment: @Scary Wombat I am only to be using arrays

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO Matthew.

Rather than giving you a solution I thought it might be useful to give you a process for solving the problem yourself.

Good practice in software development is to break your problem down into very small components, make sure each of those work perfectly (through unit testing) and then build your solution from those components.

In line with that practice I suggest you do the following:

- list each of the individual steps required to do a selection sort on paper.
- Pick the simplest one (e.g. swapping two elements).
- Write a unit test that would pass if your swap method worked
- run the unit test and verify that it fails
- write the simplest code you can to make that test pass
- write a new test to cover a more complex scenario that isn't yet supported
- keep going until you believe that method works perfectly
- move onto the next method
- once all the components are working perfectly write the method that calls them all using the same process (i.e. test first then code)

If you follow this process then you will end up with a system that you understand perfectly, works, is maintainable, and that you can refactor. It has another very significant benefit: it means when you come to SO with a question you'll be asking about a specific item that you don't know how to solve rather than a 'why doesn't my code work' question. Specific questions tend to get better and faster responses.

In your case, I would start with methods for swapping items (hint: your code for this doesn't work which you'll discover quickly when you write a unit test) and then move on to finding the smallest item in a sublist. Then a method that uses those two to put the smallest item at the start of a sublist. Finally a method that performs that method for all sublist progressively. Make sure each method is working perfectly, including checking validity of arguments, before you move on to putting them together.